# Поймать ввод текста в форме

Tags: jquery, ajax

Разрабатываю поиск с использованием технологии Ajax.
Как поймать ввод текста **вернее каждый введеный символ** в форме с идентификатором **search_text**?

Каждый введенные в форму символ - это выполнение Ajax запроса с value **search_text**

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @entithat onInput же

Comment: К полю ввода `$("input").on("change", e => {...})`

Comment: @MishaSaidov, ну да, можно и его..

Comment: Разместите комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_text">
```

Comment: Не подскажите, как одновремено проверить ещё и другие идентификаторы?

Comment: https://ideone.com/UQrkZs Идентификаторы: online, gender, photo

Comment: Если вы про `type="checkbox"` то он проверяется через `if($("input[name=online]").is(':checked')) {...}`

Comment: При вводе в форму создайте для каждого чекбокса отдельно переменную значение которой будет результат if, после при отправке отправляйте параметрами это самое значение